# Firing event from shared message service to change content of component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

As a simple example so I can grasp what is happening, I am wanting to change the message displayed in my component by simply triggering a confirmation box to appear (completed with *ngIf) and upon confirming the change, have the original message be replaced with a new one.

At the moment, messages are hard coded for ease of use.

Is there a way in which I can do this such that the message service/confirmation components can remain as generic and reusable as possible?

Here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/trigger-from-shared-message-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

in service.ts

```
eventName: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

// call function from your first component when click happens
clickEvent(): void {
    this.tabExpand.next();
}
```

then in secondComponent.ts subscribe to it

```
 this.service.eventName.subscribe(() => function());
```